# How to detect invert color mode on user side by JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, wcag, matchmedia

I'd like to know about using/unused by user invert color mode (wcag) (standard windows/mac function for visually impaired people )...this mode active or inactive. Is it possible?

I'm trying to use `window.matchMedia('(-ms-high-contrast: active)')` for Windows 
or `window.matchMedia('(inverted-colors)')` for Mac, but it doesn't work.

Is there any working solution for it by using JS/jQuery?

Comment: I don't think `-ms-high-contrast` does the same thing? Also, for Mac, is this for Safari only? Please show what you are getting as a result of both of those queries.